# On the conjugation action on the first congruence subgroup of special linear group over $p$-adic fields

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $\mathcal{O}_{L}$ be the ring of integers of a finite extension $L$ of $p$-adic number fields $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Let $\mathfrak{m}_{L}$ be the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{L}$, and let $G\subset {\rm SL}_{2}^{1}(\mathcal{O}):=\ker({\rm SL}_{2}(\mathcal{O}_{L})\twoheadrightarrow {\rm SL}_{2}(\mathcal{O}_{L}/\mathfrak{m}_{L}))$ be a non-solvable closed subgroup. Recall that a $p'$-group is a finite group of order prime to $p$. My question is the following:

> Is there a non-abelian $p'$-group $H$ of ${\rm GL}_{2}(\mathcal{O})$
> such that $\bigcap_{h\in H} hGh^{-1}$ is an open subgroup of $G$?

If $G$ is an open in ${\rm SL}_{2}^{1}(\mathcal{O})$, then $G$ always contains a characteristic open subgroup (in ${\rm SL}_{2}^{1}(\mathcal{O})$), and thus the answer is Yes where $H$ can be chosen arbitrarily. When $L=\mathbb{Q}_p$, $G$ must be an open subgroup of ${\rm SL}_{2}^{1}(\mathcal{O})$ by our assumption, and hence the answer is Yes in this case. Note that $G$ is necessarily a pro-$p$ group, and the following fact may be useful：

> Let $P$ be a pro-$p$ group with an $H$-action where $H$ is a finite $p'$-group. If $V$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p[H]$ submodule of $\overline{P}$ where $\overline{P}$ is the Frattini quotient of $P$, i.e. $\overline{P}:=P^{ab}\otimes \mathbb{F}_p$, then there exists an $H$-invariant subgroup $B$ of $P$ with $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}V$ generators mapping onto $V$.
> See [Prop. 2.3 in Boston, N., 1991. Explicit deformation of Galois representations. Inventiones mathematicae]